# How do I add an empty row to JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, tablecellrenderer

is there any way to an add empty row to jtable, where the first column is boolean, so it won't display the auto-generated checkbox?

I need it to separate groups of rows. 
I tried using the code below, but it is NOT working:

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{null,null,null,null});
```

Comment: wait....is...or isnt boolean?? You DONT want a checkbox correct?

Comment: I want make some rows completely empty so they work as separators. But in rest I would like to keep checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want make some rows completely empty so they work as separators. But in rest I would like to keep checkboxes

Instead of storing Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE in the model you would need to store null.

Then you have two options:

1. Create a custom renderer that displays the Boolean values normally and recognizes the null value and doesn't display anything.
2. Override the JTable.getCellRenderer() method. to return the renderer for the Object.class when the value is null. The default renderer for the Oject class will display null as an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{Boolean.FALSE,null,null,null});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have already tried this, but it gives same results as the previous code = an empty checkbox.

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty'? Unchecked? Have you try Boolean.TRUE if you want a checked checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

For the TableColumn instance for your first column, make a cell renderer (by implementing javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer) that renders a checkbox (javax.swing.JCheckBox) for Boolean values different from null, and renders an empty label (javax.swing.JLabel) for null values. You can't do it with providing a DefaultTableCellRenderer (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer) AFAICT.

Then set the table cell renderer property of the TableColumn instance using TableColumn.setCellRenderer